# How to change background colour of an element at index of array?

Tags: arrays, swift, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop down like this:

[image: drop down image].

I have an string array as datasource of an drop down menu.I want to give background to element at 3rd index of an array.

I have tried it in doing all things possible but not able to find out any solution.

Comment: share your code

Comment: What is kind of elements in array?

Comment: string elements...I have added picture of a dropDown that I want to create..

Comment: And you try to build a collection of buttons/view/image – which one? can you share some code?

Comment: I have this array--
var disableArr = ["A-","A+","A","AA"]
And this is how I am using it to display in a dropdown---
dropDown.anchorView = btnDisable
        dropDown.dataSource = disableArr
        let indexOfArr = self.disableArr[2]
        print(indexOfArr)
//        dropDown.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
//        dropDown.textColor = UIColor.white
        dropDown.direction = .bottom
        dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropDown.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
        dropDown.show()

Comment: Show your controller. There is still unclear

Comment: Avoid asking questions that are unclear or incomplete. Please share your source code as part of your question, so as the community can try to help you. @AadharMathur

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of similar size as your dataSource and this is only if you can't add a property of the color

```
var arr = [UIColor]()

arr = [.red,.green,.blue]

arr[2] = .orange
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I am using a dropDown here which consists of a datasource of type String array only.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type '[Colorify]' to type '[String]'...... I get this error when tried your code..

Answer (score 0):

If you insert your values to list of UIButtons (let btns : [UIButton] = [btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3]), you can do that:

```
    for i in 0..<btns.count {
        if i == 2 {
            btns[i].backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }
```

or just find needed UI-element and set needed color.